# Best tag name for Al-Amal (Hope) or Emirates Mars Mission (EMM)?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tagging

For the awkwardly titled question [Did UAE's Al-Amal (Hope) Emirates Mars Mission (EMM) launch directly into an interplanetary trajectory or did it spend some time in LEO?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/45468/12102) I've just created the tag [al-amal-emm](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/al-amal-emm).

The tag name contains both the name of the spacecraft "Al-Amal" (but not the English translation "Hope") and the acronym for the mission "EMM". Is this likely to be a usefully-named tag? Is there a better way to write it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That tag name makes sense to me. Maybe "uae-hope" could be a synonym.

Comment: Hmm... since SE should be in English, maybe uae-hope should be the tag, and al-amal and emm can be synonyms instead? Since it's only on o̶n̶e̶ two questions, it would be easy to make the change now.

Comment: Names are a bit different than most words. Usually names are written as given or transcribed, e.g. "Sputnik" not "Companion". I think al-Amal is best, and hope can be a synonym since it's used in some articles as well.

Comment: @uhoh All right, I added uae-hope as a synonym. Now if anyone types in "hope" in the tag box, al-amal-emm will pop up.

Comment: It probably needs an excerpt as well to help confirm it's the right tag.

Comment: I've added an attempt at an excerpt, please feel free to edit further. Thanks for the synonym-adding!

Comment: @uhoh Looks great! Thanks for doing that.